# Auto-scroll to section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to automatic, smooth scroll from section `#banner`, to section `#about-me` if in section `#banner` will event scroll.

I try this:

```
$('#banner').bind('scroll', function(event) {
    $(window).scrollTo($('#about-me'), 500);
});
```

but it not working. (I used scrollTo plugin).

`#banner` have height `100vh`.

Answer (score 1):

The delegation that you are looking for is `mousewheel`. You need to use `e.preventDefault();` to block the default behavior (scroll) of the browser.

**Working demo:**

```js
$('#banner').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).scrollTo('#about-me', 500);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

div {
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}

#banner {
  background:red;
}

#about-me {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.scrollto/2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner"></div>
<div id="about-me"></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/dubaza/edit?html,css,js

Comment: also check if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) for only scrolling down and bind "DOMMouseScroll" event as well (for browser support), with if(e.originalEvent.detail < 0)

Comment: Thanks.. Actually I didn't care about something else but answer his question but comments are always welcome ;)